# NGINX/PHP - ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT after long loading time

Tags: php, nginx

i dont know why, but after i update my ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04 and php from php5-fpm to php5.6-fpm my sites doesnt work anymore...

I fixed some errors with pid in nginx status, cause i had only a white clean site.
Now i have an Error Site.

```
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

What is that? I dont find error Logs in Nginx error.log or anything...

Looks like NGINX is running...

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17175/nginx -g daem
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      17175/nginx -g daem
```

service php7.0-fpm status says also active

I updated my nginx sites to php7.0-fpm.sock and this is also exists with correct group. (www-data)

Comment: Is the request even coming to Nginx or not? Do you see anything in access log?

Comment: @TarunLalwani no i dont see in access log... but idk why

Comment: This is looks like a DNS or IP issue. The request not coming to nginx indicates the correct IP is not in DNS

Comment: What you mean? Before updating to ubuntu 16.04 and php7 it was working... i dont change ip or anything in dns